# How to Add schemaLocation attribute to an XML document

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

Please view following XML namespace and schemaLocation.

```
<agr:ABWInvoice 
  xsi:schemaLocation = "
    http://services.agresso.com/schema/ABWInvoice/2011/11/14 
    http://services.agresso.com/schema/ABWInvoice/2011/11/14/ABWInvoice.xsd" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:agrlib = "http://services.agresso.com/schema/ABWSchemaLib/2011/11/14"
  xmlns:agr = "http://services.agresso.com/schema/ABWInvoice/2011/11/14"
>

</agr:ABWInvoice>
```

I have added namespaces in following way, which seems working fine:

```
XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
ns.Add("agrlib", "http://services.agresso.com/schema/ABWSchemaLib/2011/11/14");
ns.Add("agr", "http://services.agresso.com/schema/ABWInvoice/2011/11/14");
```

But, how to add following schemalocation? Any ideas?

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://services.agresso.com/schema/ABWInvoice/2011/11/14 http://services.agresso.com/schema/ABWInvoice/2011/11/14/ABWInvoice.xsd"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
xsi:schemaLocation="..."
```

is not a namespace declaration: it's an attribute (whose value happens to be a namespace, but never mind that).  So you would add it with a method that sets an attribute value.  I'm not familiar with the C# XML API, but it's probably something like this:

```
XmlElement.SetAttributeValue (localname, prefix, namespace, value)
```

`localname` should be `"schemaLocation"`
`prefix` = `"xsi"`
`namespace` = `"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`
`value` = `"your schema location"`

Comment: Thanks Mike. I did as following my answer.

Comment: For C# you can use for example the XmlDocument class, which has a method CreateAtrribute(prefix, localname, namespaceUri). It worked exactly as explained by Mike.

Answer (score 7):

The reply of Mike lead me to get following answer:

```
    [XmlAttributeAttribute("schemaLocation", AttributeName = "schemaLocation", 
    Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string SchemaLocation = "http://services.agresso.com/schema/ABWInvoice/2011/11/14 http://services.agresso.com/schema/ABWInvoice/2011/11/14/ABWInvoice.xsd";
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this code in your class

public partial class MyClass{

```
    [XmlAttribute(Namespace = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema.InstanceNamespace)]
    public string schemaLocation = "http://www.adap.cx/m3/x4 lksdjv45.xsd";
```

...
}

Answer (score 0):

For me the accepted answer did not work, but this did work:

```
    var schema = new XmlSchema();
    schema.Namespaces.Add("xmlns", "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:OrderResponse-2");
    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Schemas.Add(schema);
    var rootElement = doc.CreateElement("MyRoot");
    rootElement.SetAttribute("xmlns", "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:OrderResponse-2");
    rootElement.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
    rootElement.SetAttribute("schemaLocation", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:OrderResponse-2 file:///C:/DIGITALCAB/DigiTaxi/schema/OIOUBL/maindoc/UBL-OrderResponse-2.0.xsd");
```